# How to import oauth users from Clerk to Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, clerk

I have a full database of users that signed up while I've been using Clerk for auth. I'm thinking about migrating to Firebase for auth. If I wanted to do so, would i be able to import all these users into Firebase without the users needing to reauthenticate with Google or Microsoft?

I haven't tried this yet, mostly wondering if anyone else has encountered this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.